# What is implicitly called to output text in node prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

Take the `Date` library as an example, and the following sequence of outputs in the `node` console:

```sh
$ node
> const date = new Date()
> date
2021-05-13T18:46:41.507Z
>
> date.toString()
'Thu May 13 2021 15:49:02 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)'
```

As you can see, the output of the first "command" is different from the output of the second "command" converted to a string by the object itself.
If the node prompt made an implicit call to "toString()" in the first command, I would expect to see the same result as in the second command. However, this is not what happens, and sometimes it even leads me to wrong implementations because of this disagreement between what I see in the stdout and what the actual conversion to String results into.

Comment: What the plain `date` command returns is the current time in UTC or GMT. What `toString()` does is to return this timestamp in a human readable form considering your time zone. They put some convenience in it.

Comment: Honestly speaking. I don't know what your program is supposed to do but when working with time you should always use the Unix-timestamp as milliseconds. This is the least problematic approach.

Comment: I agree with the UNIX timestamp approach, unfortunately I'm working with a third-party api that requests date in this format.

Comment: About your first comment, I'm beginning to understand..

Comment: The problem is that `date` itself isn't a command per se, is it? There has to be another layer extracting something from this Date object (date)